# Getting the vars of an external php script

Tags: php, include

I have two vars running on an external site and I am calling the script from another url.

**How can I get these vars from one external script in my other script?**

Example: MyVars.php

```
<?
$One = "This is one";
$Two = "This is two";
?>
```

Script on another server: GetVars.php

```
<?
include 'http://www.MySite.com/MyVars.php';

echo $One . $Two;
?>
```

The vars are not showing up on the second site. Is there a way I can access them?

Thanks
-Ed

Answer (score 2):

You can't include a remote script the way you're trying to, particularly as executable code.   The remote .php script will almost certainly be (and should be) *executed* by the remote server, and only its output (i.e. the stuff it `echo`s) will be returned to the requesting client (i.e. your code).

You should download whatever PHP script you need, upload it to your server, then include it locally.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Including files, basically "smashes" the PHP scripts into one large PHP that the server executes. Try including the file with a relative URL.

UPDATE: Sorry, didn't see the part about you *need* to pull it from an external site. Hmm... if you own that site, you would need to find someway to access it with a relative URL. For security reasons, you cannot include scripts from another site/server like you are doing.

Comment: *smashes* them together, kind of like the function argument orders have been? :P

Answer (score 0):

The script is on another server? I would imagine that would cause problems. You wouldn't be able to include anything (if you could, serious security problems would arise). The two files *must* be on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual, you may be able to do this, but use Get to retrieve the values of $One and $Two

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php